# Finding the averege in a loop counting to 100

Tags: php

I need to find the averege after using a loop counting ever 3rd to a 100. The loop part is easy enough, but I need to sum every value then divide the sum on the total of values.

```
for ($x = 3; $x < 100; $x+=3) {
    echo $x.", ";
}
```

This is the loop I need to use. How to I sum the values this produces and how do I find how many values this loop produces?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the intention here is to learn about loops, otherwise this stuff can be done without looping too.

For learning purpose, you can simply introduce two variables `count` and `sum` and compute them inside the loop. For `count`, you just increment it on each iteration. For sum, you add the current value of `x` into `sum`. After the loop you print both variables.

```
$count = 0;
$sum = 0;
for ($x = 3; $x < 100; $x+=3) {
    echo $x.", ";
    $count++;
    $sum+=$x;
}

echo $sum;
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

add your elements into an array and then use array_sum to sum the array elements , then divide the sum by the count of your array

```
$arr = [];
for ($x = 3; $x < 100; $x+=3) {
    // echo $x.", \n";
    $arr[] = $x;
}

print_r(array_sum($arr) / count($arr));
// Output : 51
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
$tempx=0;
for ($x = 3; $x < 100; $x+=3) {
    //total sum
    $tempx = $tempx + $x;  
    //count of how many times the loop ran in this case 33 times
    $i++;

     }

//first $i was 0 so we add 1
$i=$i + 1;
//getting the average
$average=$tempx / $i;
echo $average;
//output
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last answer i think we should not do:

> //first $i was 0 so we add 1 $i=$i + 1;

Regards